# Android GLSurfaceView keep GL resources after pause/resume

Tags: java, android

If I start for example "Clash of Clans" on android than pause it(Go to the home screen) and than resume to it, "Clash of Clans" is instantly back in the game without loading any resources.
How is that possible ?
Because if I use the "GLSurfaceView" in my own app the GL context is always released if I pause the app, so I have to load all resources again.
Can someone tell me how "Clash of Clans" made it possible?